# Inspiron 15 fan doesn't work

Tags: xubuntu, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

**System configuration**

- Win10 and Xubuntu 15.04 Dual boot
- i5 4200U
- Radeon 8850M
- Latest BIOS from dell
- `tlp` on Xubuntu installed. No more tweaks.
- `coretemp` module was loaded
- `fglrx` is not installed
- Idle cpu temperature =  `47° C` Windows;   `51° C` Ubuntu

**The Problem**

I have been using Ubuntu/Xubuntu for about 6 months. I have never heard the fan spin up as much it does in Windows. So, I gathered some info on this,

- I stress tested Xubuntu by making all cores go to 100%. `sensors` temperature reading shot upto `75° C` and yet, the fan wasn't spinning up. The temperature kept on rising and I stopped the stress test immediately.
- Now, back to Windows, I started a render task (with CPU) and as soon as the temperature hit `68° C`, the fan was at its maximum speed. The temperature didn't exceed `68° C` till the end of rendering.

**The Question**

- Why doesn't the fan spin up in Xubuntu? Isn't the fan supposed to spin up when CPU temperature shoots up?
- How can I fix this?

**Update:**

I opened the case of my laptop and verified that the fan was not working when I run Ubuntu. The current temperature is `48° C`

**Update 2:**

I used `i8kutils` to run the fan at full speed and got the temperature down to `42° C`

Comment: If you have installed and configured i8kutils does this mean your problem is solved?